# How do I declare structures in my .C file?

Tags: c, struct, header, structure, declare

I have to implement a Linked List in C, and according to the project specifications, the following structures must be created in my header file:

```
typedef struct node {
char *string;
struct node* next;  
} 


typedef struct {
node *head;  /* could have been struct node* as well */
node *tail;
} list;
```

Now how do I make these available in my .C file? I've already #included the Header file, but when I try to call, for example, myList.head, I keep getting errors stating I'm trying to perform actions on something that is not a struct or union, so how do I fix this?

Comment: A side-note, as far as I know, .C is a conventional extension for C++ files rather than C files, at least when using gcc

Comment: The header file should be called `myList.h`, not `.head`. For further questions please always include the actual error message of your compiler. Too much information gets lost by paraphrasing.

Comment: @Kay "The header file should be called myList.h, not .head" -- Um, it should be pretty obvious that 'myList' is `list*`, not a filename, and `head` is a member of `list`, not a filename extension, and that the OP wants `myList->head`. "myList->head" would be a problematic filename.

Comment: @AdelQodmani That doesn't hold for the dominant OS, which ignores the case of filenames.

Comment: @JimBalter Windows _preserves_ the case of the filename. That's all that what a compiler needs. I interpreted myList.head wrong, though.

Comment: myList is not a header file, it is a list struct, a struct which is declared as seen above (though the missing semicolon was a typo on my part here). Now, in my C file, which is the Linked List, I have methods whose parameters are pointers to lists. When I try to look at the head of the list passed in by saying, for example, myList.head, I'm being told that myList is not a struct, when it is.

Comment: "Windows preserves the case of the filename" -- So what? It's not uncommon in the Windows environment to have all uppercase filenames, and it would be a disaster to base the language on the filename case in that environment.

Answer (score 3):

You need a semicolon after your first `struct`.
And either get rid of your `typedef`, or give it a name too.

Comment: The typedef'd name is missing, too.

Comment: Missing semi colon isnt in the actual code, it was a mistake when I was typing the code in here

Answer (score 3):

Your `typedef` is wrong.  The syntax is:

```
typedef [some_type_definition] [type_name];
```

The type definition is this:

```
struct node {
    char *string;
    struct node* next;
};
```

So you need to prefix it with `typedef` and suffix it with `node` (before the semi-colon).  This will allow you to refer to the structure using either `node` or `struct node`.

For your list, you didn't name the struct, but you did `typedef` it.  That means you cannot refer to it as `struct list` - you must use just `list`.  You can name the struct if you want.

Comment: But my question is, if all this is in my header file, how do I accurately use the struct in my actual c file?

Comment: In my C file, I have methods getting passed in lists and nodes, but when I try to access the list contents (for example the head of the list passed in) I'm being told that the struct isn't a struct... which it is

Comment: You just include the header.  If you declare your types properly, then when you define variables or pointers of that type, all will be fine.  If you have `list myList`, then you can access `myList.head`.  If you have `list *myList`, you access as `myList->head`.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. Any idea why I'm getting an 'invalid initializer' error when I do this?

    int llSize(list *myList){
 

 node decoy = myList->head;

Comment: Yeah, you are trying to initialise an instance of `node` with a `node*` pointer.  If you want to copy the entire node, you must do `node decoy = *myList->head`.  If you just want to copy the pointer, you must do `node *decoy = myList->head`.